# SMS sending Time android

Tags: android

I am reading the sent messages from android messages log and i want to get the sending time for each message, i tried to get it from the date like the following but it didn't work, the date comes without time :

```
Cursor c = null;
            Date datecom = null;
            try {
                c = activity.getContentResolver().query(allMessages, null,
                        null, null, "date DESC");
        Date date=new Date(c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex("date")));
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't have time? Can you show a log of the `date`'s `toString()`

Comment: I tried it and it returns as this format 2013-6-21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Date always includes the time component as well. Try to use the following code to display the time value:

```
Log.debug("tag", "date=" + date.toGMTString());
```

This should display someting like: `22 Jun 1999 13:02:00 GMT`. Also, you can use the various getters of the Date class to get the time value, e.g. `getHours()`, `getMinutes()`

If the time component is still not there, then let me know.